# Django self-recursive model. How to query and template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-orm

How to setup a query that creates a set that gives me following result:

```
-Parent1
 -Child1
  -Subchild1
  -Subchild2
 -Child2
  -Subchild3
-Parent2
 -Child3
```

I´m trying for a while now, but i´m not getting there. I´m not even Sure if the Problem is in the View or the template.

**Models:**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Child(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subchild = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Basic Query that isn´t giving me the results i want. Works with just the childs atleast.

**Views.py:**

```
def template(request):
    parents = Parent.objects.all()
    context = {'parents':parents}
    return render(request, 'myapp/template.html', context)
```

**Template.html:**

```
<ul>
{% for parent in parents %}
  <li>{{ parent.name }}</li>
<ul>
    {% for child in parent.child_set.all %}
    <li>{{ child.name }}</li>
        <ul>
        {% for subchild in child.subchild_set.all %}
        <li>{{ subchild.name }}</li>        
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you at least get something? I mean in any level of your loops?

Comment: Yes i get the Parent + Children + subchildren, but the subchildren are below parent and not below the Parent.Child